# Foreach PHP Error while using Steam API

Tags: php, foreach, steam

With the following code I get the error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

```
$apifr = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=".$steamkey."&steamids=".$id_banuser."&avatar";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$apifr);

$result=curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($result);
$result = $result->response->players;

foreach($result as $r){
    echo $r->avatarfull;
}
curl_close($ch);
```

All suggestions are accepted :)

Comment: There is something declaring steamkey and id_banuser it just didnt show

Comment: The `$result` variable isn't an array, you can't pass it into `foreach`, insead `echo` or `var_dump` it

Comment: var_dump($result) just outputs NULL

Comment: Thats the reason it can't be passed into a foreach...

Comment: I'm not very fluent in PHP, How would I fix this if you know?

Code is here : http://ideone.com/QknJPZ